# vba code to get data from the body of pre style from url

Tags: vba

I am trying to get data from the body of `pre` style but i am not able to do that request you to please help me!

below is the data which I require from body.

```
{"response": {"objects": [["natural_light", 612, 881, 1124, 1118]]}, "error": "false"}
```

**my html code:-**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
{"response": {"objects": [["natural_light", 612, 881, 1124, 1118]]}, "error": "false"}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
{"response": {"objects": [["natural_light", 612, 881, 1124, 1118]]}, "error": "false"}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
Sub test()
Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim results As MSHTML.HTMLDivElement
Dim elt As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell
Dim imgs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim img As MSHTML.HTMLImg
Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
With xhr
.Open "GET", "https://api.restb.ai/segmentation client_key=c529e4cb36fd71a0038e5790fd69a42eacaf378fa0789bba78b9782e073b88ed&model_id=re_features&image_url=https://www.mulderteam.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/234/files/2013/04/110922317.jpg", False
.send
If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End If
End With
End Sub
```

my vba code:-